# Azure Search, using prefix with Scoring Profile

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

When using a prefix like "tru*" I see the score of the results are stopped been calculated against the Scoring Profile.

I'm looking for a solution to searching part of a word and also order the results.

Two images show a search with '*' and without,

[image: Here without * the Scoring is working]

[image: Here with * the Scoring do not work]

Comment: That is unexpected behavior. Can you please edit your question to include more details about what you were trying to do, and what you observed? Thanks.

Comment: Could you let us know which region your service is located at? Feel free to contact me directly at nateko _AT_ microsoft.com

Comment: I add photos showing the difference between using * and not using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually the Scoring Profile does work, but since using '*' the base Score is so low that no difference is shown after scoring profile.

The best solution for me was using Order By in the search request.